# Create async instances of loops and manage them

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, promise

I am using a chrome extension to activate infinite async instances of loops so they do not conflict with each other.

There is a list of values and one item is being passed to each individual loop. Those loops are executed in the content.js and are being managed by the background.js but they are initialized, started and cancelled from the popup.js.

Now big Question is how do I use best practices to make the management of multiple async loops as easy as possible?
Is there any possible way to also cancel these loops in an easy way?

example code:

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
     function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if(request.message.active){
      console.log("do something");
      dispatch(request.message);
}});


async function dispatch(alternator) {
    if (alternator.active) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, alternator.timeout));
        console.log("do something");
    }
    return;
}
```

This background.js should have a list of async loops to manage in an array or something easy to manage. The for-loop is consuming too much time and the timeout is causing too much load.

background.js

```
async function dispatchBackground() {
    while (1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < alternator.length; i++) {
            if(alternator[i].active){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(alternator[i].tab_id, {"message": alternator[i]});
            }
        }
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: WebWorkers will enable you to move work off the main thread of execution. If WebWorkers or Worker threads are not available, then I don't think it'd be too difficult to write a very simple task scheduler that allocates slices of time to a managed queue of callbacks. But it would probably have to be cooperative.

Comment: 1) WebWorkers won't help here because the background script is a service worker and it can't create nested workers. Also, if sending a message takes a long time then it's a separate problem, which can be solved by using a different format or a different delivery mechanism. 2) As for canceling, just check a global flag that can be an object with props or a single boolean.

Comment: Check out [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops), it has great flexibility when it comes to handling async loops, including such logic as [timeout](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use [a library](https://github.com/miketalbot/js-coroutines).

...but that would be boring!

In the following  code, `macrotask` uses `requestIdleCallback` to run a callback on a JS runtime macrotask.

The user supplies the data to process, the logic to run (synchronously) at each step, and the continuation condition; they do not have to worry about explicitly yielding to an API.

Function `createTask` constructs a generator to return steps until the `continuationPredicate` returns false. Generator functions enable us to suspend and resume synchronous code - which we need to do here to switch between tasks in a round-robin fashion. A more advanced solution could prioritise tasks according to a heuristic.

`createCircularList` returns a wrapper around an array that exposes `add`, `remove`, and `next` (get the next item in creation order or, if we are at the "end", loop around to the first item again).

`createScheduler` maintains the task list. While there are tasks remaining in the task list, this function will identify the next task, schedule its next step on a macrotask, and wait for that step to complete. If that was the final step in the current task, the task is then removed from the task list.

Note that the precise interleaving of the output of this code will depend on things like how busy your machine is. The intent of the demonstration is to show how the task queue can be added-to while it is being drained.

```js
const log = console.log
const nop = () => void 0
const stepPerItem = (_, i, data) => i < data.length
const macrotask = (cb) => (...args) => new Promise((res) => (typeof requestIdleCallback ? requestIdleCallback : setTimeout)(() => res(cb(...args))))

const createTask = (data, 
                    step, 
                    continuePredicate = stepPerItem, 
                    acc = null, 
                    onDone = nop) => 
    (function*(i = 0) {
        while(continuePredicate(acc, i, data)) {
            acc = step(acc, i, data)
            yield [acc, onDone]
            i++
        }
        return [acc, onDone]
    })()

const createCircularList = (list = []) => {
    const add = list.push.bind(list)
    const remove = (t) => list.splice(list.indexOf(t), 1)
    
    const nextIndex = (curr, currIndex = list.indexOf(curr)) =>
        (currIndex === list.length - 1) ? 0 : currIndex + 1
    
    const next = (curr) =>
        list.length ? list[nextIndex(curr)] : null
    
    return { add, remove, next }
}

const createScheduler = (tasks = createCircularList()) => {    
    let isRunning = false
    
    const add = (...tasksToAdd) =>        
        (tasksToAdd.forEach((t) => tasks.add(t)), 
         !isRunning && (isRunning = true, go()))
    
    const remove = tasks.remove.bind(tasks)
    
    const go = async (t = null) => {
        while(t = tasks.next(t))
            await macrotask(({ done, value: [result, onDone] } = t.next()) =>
                done && (tasks.remove(t), onDone(result)))()            
        isRunning = false
    }
    
    return { add, remove }
}

const scheduler = createScheduler()
const task1 = createTask([...Array(5)], (_, i) => log('task1', i))
const task2 = createTask([...Array(5)], (_, i) => log('task2', i))
const task3 = createTask([...Array(5)], (_, i) => log('task3', i))

scheduler.add(task1, task2)
setTimeout(() => scheduler.add(task3), 50) // you may need to fiddle with the `setTimeout` delay here to observe meaningful interleaving
```